# Fatal error: Call to a member function

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I try to get status of stock but i get this error message:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getIsInStock() on null with
>   $stockProduct = $product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock();

I got this error message when i try to create a new product.

I'm using observer: catalog_product_save_after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can really use this event `catalog_product_save_after` and you do something like this:

```
public function productStatus($observer) {
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    $stockStatus = $product->getStockItem()->getData();

}
```

**The collection :**

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
foreach ($products as $_product) {
    $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product);
    echo $stock->getQty();
    echo $stock->getMinQty();
    echo $stock->getMinSaleQty();
}
```

Nb: We can't get stock directly from product, you need an join.

Comment: I want to get the stock status, and i get this with $product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock(), but I'm getting a fatal error.

Comment: Yes use this : $newStatus = $product->getStatus(); or use $newStatus = $product->getData(); then select what you want

Comment: and how can i select the status of stock? and this will return to me a boolean value?

Comment: Look my update please

Comment: anyone help me to solve add to cart button error -> code -> https://justpaste.it/49eqz